# List of words with " o' " in it

Tags: meaning, terminology

I searched google, but I do not know what words like "one o'clock", "jack o'lantern", "lily o'the valley" are called.

Does any list exist? The motivation is just out of curiosity. (Reading a lot of Dickens which made me wonder about it.)

Thank you for the answer and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called contractions. Others include:

- *cat-o’-nine-tails*
- *hop-o’-my-thumb*
- *o’er*
- *tam-o’-shanter*
- *thick o’ fog*
- *Tom o’ Bedlam*
- *tot-o’er-seas*
- *o’ my conscience*
- *warpling o’ the green*
- *will-o’-the-wisp*

This is not a closed set. People make them at the drop o’ their hat.

Comment: There are also thousands of Irish surnames like this.

Comment: That's an impressive list. Where did you find them?

Comment: Thank you so much! That was fast. As chasly asked, do you have a link for a complete list?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Perl magic: I merely grepped the OED for `\bo'`. If you don't restrict it to word boundaries with `\b` then you get answers that included things like *po’boy*, which is a type of sandwich, or *St Elmo’s fire*, which is a will-o’-the-wisp.

Comment: Do you have to have a subscription for the OED?  Where's the machine-readable text?